# how to input newly created pdf link into google sheet column

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, google-sheets, hyperlink, geturl

I tried multiple ways, but for a few days, none worked for me.

This is my script. I manage to create the doc and also the pdf. I inputted the document link but what I want is a pdf link. I couldn't get the getUrl function right for my pdf created.

Can anyone just let me know what I should put in? Many thanks in advance.

```
 function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Create Form');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();

}
function createNewGoogleDocs() {

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1wROa5kWXGvsOSaeb_34ncF_vcbWA4SFXGuXkwCqjAW0');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1qld3qQDQNtaGdoOxQCsSre1VjWQ6NKGn')
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){

    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[23]) return;

    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form` , destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[18]).toLocaleDateString();

    body.replaceText('{{Submission Date}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Case ID}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Contact Number}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Main Service}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Type}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{Brand}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{Model}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{IMEI No. Or Serial No.}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{Warranty}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{Password/Pattern}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{Format}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{Include Parts}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Issues}}', row[13]);
    body.replaceText('{{Full Address}}', row[14]);
    body.replaceText('{{Choose One}}', row[15]);
    body.replaceText('{{Details}}', row[16]);
    body.replaceText('{{Status}}', row[17]);
    body.replaceText('{{Collection Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Special Case Reject Reason}}', row[19]);
    body.replaceText('{{Quotation}}', row[20]);
    body.replaceText('{{Collection Date}}', row[21]);
    body.replaceText('{{Installation Date}}', row[22]);

    doc.saveAndClose();

const pdfContentBlob = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    DriveApp.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form`);

const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 24).setValue(url)
    
    })}
```

when I put in pdfContentBlob there's no geturl function. I am not good at this at all. I hope to have someone able to give me the line of codes I just need to put in to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, `const url = doc.getUrl();` is used as the URL. In this case, the URL is for Google Document. When you want to retrieve the URL of the PDF file, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
    DriveApp.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form`);

const url = doc.getUrl();
```

#### To:

```
const url = DriveApp.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form`).getUrl();
```

- If you want to save the PDF file to the folder of `destinationFolder`, please modify it as follows.

  ```
    const url = destinationFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form`).getUrl();
  ```

#### Note:

- In your script, `setValue` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes a bit high. If you want to reduce the process cost, I think that the following modification might be able to be used.

```js
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('###'); // Please set your document ID.
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###'); // Please set your folder ID.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const [, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const values = rows.map(function (row) {
    if (row[23]) return [row[23]];
    console.log("Passed1")
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form`, destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[18]).toLocaleDateString();
    body.replaceText('{{Submission Date}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Case ID}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Contact Number}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Main Service}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Type}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{Brand}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{Model}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{IMEI No. Or Serial No.}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{Warranty}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{Password/Pattern}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{Format}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{Include Parts}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Issues}}', row[13]);
    body.replaceText('{{Full Address}}', row[14]);
    body.replaceText('{{Choose One}}', row[15]);
    body.replaceText('{{Details}}', row[16]);
    body.replaceText('{{Status}}', row[17]);
    body.replaceText('{{Collection Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Special Case Reject Reason}}', row[19]);
    body.replaceText('{{Quotation}}', row[20]);
    body.replaceText('{{Collection Date}}', row[21]);
    body.replaceText('{{Installation Date}}', row[22]);
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const pdfContentBlob = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    const url = DriveApp.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form`).getUrl(); // or const url = destinationFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(`${row[1]} - ${row[2]} Order Form`).getUrl();
    return [url];
  });
  sheet.getRange(2, 24, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Amazing it works perfectly and your explanation is so easy to understand!

Comment: @Nelita Chan About `Amazing it works perfectly and your explanation is so easy to understand!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer